"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: IOException". Trouble with Eclipse+Tomcat in Java/JSP
I've started working on my first webapp and decided to use Java and I am trying to develop using Eclipse IDE and Apache Tomcat v10.19. However, after setting up Eclipse with Tomcat (which give me some issues), and starting work on basic UI, I tried running my login page that I made but instead ran into an error stating "'Starting Tomcat v10.1 Server at localhost' has encountered a problem. Server Tomcat 10.1 Server at localhost failed to start." and I am not given any further details. When trying to look at the console, there is so much going on that I am not sure what is wrong and what to do. I just see that some exceptions seem to have been thrown and that components failed to start.
So far I have tried deleting my Tomcat 10.1 server and its configuration and restarted the server. I was thinking that this was a server issue and that this would fix it, but it did not, leaving me to assume the issue is in my code.
Below is my AASLoginServlet.java, Login.jsp, web.xml code. I'll also show my directories and the errors showing up.
AASLoginServlet.java
package Login;

import java.io.IOException;

import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
/**
 * Servlet implementation class AASLoginServlet
 */
public class AASLoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public AASLoginServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}

Login.jsp
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>

<div align = center>
<h1>Student Login</h1>
</div>
<form action = AASLoginServlet method = post>
<table>
<tr><td>Enter Email:</td><td><input type=text name =textemail></td></tr>
<tr><td>Enter Password:</td><td><input type=password name =textpassword></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type=submit value=login></td><td><input type=reset></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>

Web.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee" xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_6_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="6.0">
  <display-name>AASLogin</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>AASLoginServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>AASLoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Login.AASLoginServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AASLoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/AASLoginServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>

Directories

Errors (Something not found on java library path?)
Apr 16, 2024 2:49:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/10.1.20
Apr 16, 2024 2:49:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Mar 19 2024 12:49:58 UTC
Apr 16, 2024 2:49:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version number: 10.1.20.0
Apr 16, 2024 2:49:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10
Apr 16, 2024 2:49:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.0
Apr 16, 2024 2:49:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Apr 16, 2024 2:49:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-22
Apr 16, 2024 2:49:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           22+36-2370
Apr 16, 2024 2:49:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Apr 16, 2024 2:49:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\alial\AASLogin\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Apr 16, 2024 2:49:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.1
Apr 16, 2024 2:49:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\alial\AASLogin\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Apr 16, 2024 2:49:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.1
Apr 16, 2024 2:49:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\alial\AASLogin\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
Apr 16, 2024 2:49:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
Apr 16, 2024 2:49:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
Apr 16, 2024 2:49:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
Apr 16, 2024 2:49:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
Apr 16, 2024 2:49:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
Apr 16, 2024 2:49:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Apr 16, 2024 2:49:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dstdout.encoding=UTF-8
Apr 16, 2024 2:49:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dstderr.encoding=UTF-8
Apr 16, 2024 2:49:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages
Apr 16, 2024 2:49:22 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-22\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-22/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-22/bin;C:/Users/alial/AppData/Local/Temp/eoiA69.tmp//plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.minimal.stripped.win32.x86_64_17.0.10.v20240120-1143/jre/bin/server;C:/Users/alial/AppData/Local/Temp/eoiA69.tmp//plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.minimal.stripped.win32.x86_64_17.0.10.v20240120-1143/jre/bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Pulse Secure\VC142.CRT\X64\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Pulse Secure\VC142.CRT\X86\;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Users\alial\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\alial\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\alial\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\MinGW\bin;;C:\Users\alial\Downloads;;C:\Users\alial\Downloads;;.]
Apr 16, 2024 2:49:23 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8082"]
Apr 16, 2024 2:49:23 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Server initialization in [789] milliseconds
Apr 16, 2024 2:49:23 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
Apr 16, 2024 2:49:23 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.20]
Apr 16, 2024 2:49:23 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal

Errors #2 (Child container failed at start?
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/AASLogin]]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:873)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:845)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:433)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:921)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:757)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/AASLogin]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:419)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:186)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: IOException
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3601)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2686)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredMethods(Introspection.java:121)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadMethodsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:319)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:964)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:114)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4796)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: IOException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1353)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1165)
    ... 38 more

Errors #3 (Child container failed at start?
Apr 16, 2024 2:49:23 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:873)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:433)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:921)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:757)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:885)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:845)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/AASLogin]]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:873)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/AASLogin]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:419)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:186)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: IOException
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3601)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2686)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredMethods(Introspection.java:121)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadMethodsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:319)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:964)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:114)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4796)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: IOException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1353)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1165)
    ... 38 more

Final errors (Required server component failed)
Apr 16, 2024 2:49:23 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:885)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:433)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:921)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:757)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:873)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:885)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:845)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/AASLogin]]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:873)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/AASLogin]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:419)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:186)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: IOException
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3601)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2686)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredMethods(Introspection.java:121)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadMethodsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:319)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:964)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:114)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4796)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: IOException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1353)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1165)
    ... 38 more

Apr 16, 2024 2:49:23 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8082"]
Apr 16, 2024 2:49:23 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service [Catalina]
Apr 16, 2024 2:49:23 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8082"]

Below is the page I am trying to run through my tomcat server (Login.jsp)

For clarification, "Errors #1, #2, #3" and "Final Errors" all came from one attempt of starting my tomcat server. But eclipse separated them so I thought I would too.
Looking at some of these errors, I can see clearly some components failed to open which is probably why tomcat couldn't launch, but I'm not sure how to resolve them. It's very possible that it's a dumb mistake and might even be a typo, but I'd appreciate any help on where I'm going wrong.

Please don't post code as images, those are unreadable. Add them as text with proper code tags.

You have a red 'X' on your source file. What Problem message is associated with it?
